# How to use variable from JSR223 in MQTT request

Tags: jmeter

I have following script in JSR223:

```
    setStrictJava (true);

   int a = 0; // Creating a Variable
   int b = 1; // Creating a Variable

   int S = a - b; // 

   log.info(S + " - Subtraction Operation");
   vars.put("T1", S)
```

Added, I have MQTT request, where i need to use the T1 output (-1) but it doesn't return anything.

Sure i am missing few basic. pls any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can save an [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) using [vars.put()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) function as it takes 2 [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) as the parameters, so my expectation is that you need to explicitly convert your `S` variable to String like:

```
vars.put("T1", S as String)
```

If you need the variable as the Integer in your MQTT logic you can use [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) function instead like:

```
vars.putObject("T1", S)
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)